# DB2 Stored Procedure returning Multiple rows of a Cursor in C Program

Tags: c, db2

I want to write a Stored Procedure in DB2 which will have a curosor for a table and then it will send the whole cursor rows to a C program?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: On what system? You have to give us a bit more info.

Comment: If you're returning whole 'cursor rows', do you just want to return a table?  What is your statement?  Cursors are often seen as a stopgap measure for dealing with certain program limits, there are often (better) set-based solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GETNAMESET ( IN CNUM INTEGER )
RESULT SET 1
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN    
--Take the inputted customer number, CNUM and
--return the record(s) for that customer from the
--customer table via SQL result set(s)
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM CUSTTABLE WHERE CUSTNUM = CNUM;
  OPEN C1;
  SET RESULT SETS CURSOR C1;
END;
```